# Python - how to print values of a list given many indexes?

Tags: python, list, printing, indices

I have for example the index values:

```
x = [1, 4, 5, 7]
```

and I have a list of elements:

```
y = ['this','is','a','very','short','sentence','for','testing']
```

I want to return the values

```
['is','short','sentence','testing']
```

When I attempt to print say:

```
y[1]
```

it will gladly return `['is']`. However, when I do `print(y[x]))` it will simply return nothing. How can I print all those indexes? Bonus: Then join them together.

Comment: What do you mean by join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
' '.join([y[i] for i in x])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this list comp `[y[i] for i in x]`

```
>>> y = ['this','is','a','very','short','sentence','for','testing']
>>> x = [1, 4, 5, 7]
>>> [y[i] for i in x]                    # List comprehension to get strings
['is', 'short', 'sentence', 'testing']
>>> ' '.join([y[i] for i in x])          # Join on that for your bonus
'is short sentence testing'
```

Other ways

```
>>> list(map(lambda i:y[i], x) )         # Using map
['is', 'short', 'sentence', 'testing']
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a for loop to iterate through your list of indexes and then axes your list with the indexes.

```
for i in x: #x is your list, i will take the 'value' of the numbers in your list and will be your indexed
    print y[i]

    > is
      short
      sentence
      testing
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `numpy` package, you can do like this

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = np.array(['this','is','a','very','short','sentence','for','testing'])
>>> x = np.array([1,4,5,7])
>>> print y[x]
['is' 'short' 'sentence' 'testing']
```